# Is line level Bluetooth audio possible with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, lightning

In my car i have a 3.5mm jack that I want to connect to my iPhone 5. I currently am just running a standard 3.5mm cable from my phone to the port, but that audio volume isn't that great. So I thought a neat way would be to get a Bluetooth module with a 3.5mm input - like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008RWQLK6) one and use that.

But I'm not sure if that would connect via a line level output from the phone.

Is is possible to do line level out without needing an expensive lighting to 30 pin cable -> 30 pin to 3.5mm cable into the car port?

OR is it possible to just go lighting cable to this, right into the 3.5mm jack, would it carry audio???

(there was a goo.gl link here but it led to a 404 or I removed it)

Comment: Whenever I plug my phone into my car, I turn the volume (on the phone) up to max, and then down 1-2 clicks. The volume as controlled by the car dashboard is then equivalent to radio/CD content.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like the [Griffin BlueTrip Aux](http://store.griffintechnology.com/itrip-aux-bluetooth) as it gets powered from a DC car jack (a.k.a cigarette lighter recepticle) and receives bluetooth music and sends it out a stereo analog connector to your car's AUX in / line in headphone jack.

There are many similar products that are cheaper and larger and the audio quality on some is not as good as Griffin's product, but you can shop around since there are several similar product on the market.

The part you list needs a USB cable and getting that out of a lightning port phone would be far more product than a simple BT receiver.

Comment: Is bluetooth line level? The headphone jack is not, it's powered. Not sure if bluetooth audio is line level or not.

Comment: Since the car stereo is designed to take input from a headphone amplified signal and line level is less than that, you should be fine. Unless your car amplifier is really poor, you shouldn't have any clipping of the signal or large amounts of noise.

Comment: Thanks. The problem i'm running into is low volume, so I guess i just thought that a line level signal would improve the volume since it could provide a cleaner signal and thus the amp not work as hard.

Comment: As bmike says, the signal coming out of your headphone port is (potentially) stronger than the 1volt peak to peak line level signal. To match this level it is usually best to set your iphone's volume to 70-80% of maximum. Your car stereo, unless it is faulty, should be able to take this signal and boost it to the same levels as your onboard radio etc.

Comment: Bluetooth audio is a digital format. The bluetooth audio itself is neither "line level" nor "headphone level." It's what a bluetooth receiver puts out that you would want to know about—and that's going to vary by product.